# Jasmin SMPP Euro Sign

Tags: smpp, euro, jasmin-sms

how could i send a euro sign using Jasmin http api?

What I've tried:

- %80
- %E2%82%AC

Parameter coding=0, 1, 3 and empty.

Im always just getting "?" in the SMS. It works fine when directly connection via HTTP instead of SMPP to my provider.

Comment: I dont know if that is a coincidence or a wished behaviour, but i've noticed that if i send %a4 with no coding parameter i get the euro sign. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

SMPP allows multiple data coding schemes and it is not clear which one you are using. Have you looked at http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv34_gsmumts_ig_v10.pdf to see the options and how the map to mobile usage?

For the GSM 7bit alphabet the EUR sign is available as a special escape (http://www.developershome.com/sms/gsmAlphabet.asp). I don't know how to express the desire of using 7bit encoding in Jasmin.

If your SMS is short enough using UCS2 might be the easiest option for you.